# Getting wrong answers from predefined Calendar function in java

Tags: java, calendar, java-time, date, java-calendar

I want get a ans of my java program where I want to find out that current day is  which day of year, current week is which week of year etc. When I am trying to do this with calendar class methods, it is giving wrong answer.

Below is my code

```
{
            Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            c1.setTime(new Date());
            System.out.println("Today is "+Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR+" day of year");
            System.out.println("Today is "+Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR+" week of year");
            System.out.println("Today is "+Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH+" day of week in month");



    }
```

Output:-

```
  Today is 6 day of year
    Today is 3 week of year
    Today is 8 day of week in month
```

Can anyone please help to find out solution?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Those values you're printing are constants. You need to [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) the field value from the `Calendar` object. `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")` — That warning you are suppressing is telling you that you're using `Calendar` wrongly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: you have to use the constants on the `c1.get` method ... they are just integer constants that point to a  position of the corresponding particular value in a field of the Calendar object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Calendar` variable is `c1`.  But this doesn't reference `c1` at all:

```
Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR
```

So what is it?  [According to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) those are constants which identify the fields to return when querying that object.  You don't want to output the constant itself, you want to use it to get the value from your `c1` object.  Something like this:

```
System.out.println("Today is " + c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + " day of year");
```

Repeat for your other fields as well.